# What is the best way to model a bank account manager with actors?

Tags: akka, actor

I've started working on a banking integration and thinking of going for a reactive approach with Akka actors. Would it be a good idea to have an actor hierachy like the following ?

```
account-manager -> account -> transaction
```

My plan is to have a transaction actor spawned for each transaction. I'm thinking of maintaing the transaction state in the transaction actor and it would help in recovering from failures as per my understanding.  Would this be a good approach ?

Comment: One actor per transaction sounds like it would result in too many actors. Since transactions stay around forever, you will continuously accumulate actors as transactions increase. You are theoretically able to have millions of actors on a single machine, but I think one actor for every transaction is not a good abstraction. I would keep transactions as some kind of data structure, like an IndexedSeq or Map, in the account actor. account-manager -> account makes sense to me.

Comment: @AllenHan What if we destroy transaction actor instances once they are completed ?
Wouldn't that solve the accumulation of transaction actor instances ?

Comment: Yes, that would work then. There's nothing wrong with creating and killing actors as you go. I think it can work.